# Ruby on Rails update_attibutes not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, update-attributes

I am trying to set an user as admin, the method is:

```
def set_user_admin
    if admin_true? == true
      user = User.find(params[:format])
      if user == nil
        redirect_to managements_path
      else
        user.update_attributes(admin: true, assistant: true, 
          businessman: true)
        redirect_to managements_path
        flash[:notice] = "The user #{user.name} is an admin user now"
      end
    else
    end
  end
```

The method run just fine, but is not saving in data base. Some validation is stopping the action. Then I run the command in terminal:

```
u = User.find_by_id(3)
u.update_attributes(admin: true)
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction
=> false
u.errors
@messages={:password=>["Choose a password", "Your password must be at least 4 characters
"], :password_confirmation=>["You must confirm your password
"]}
```

So, I can't update user as admin because the password validations are called in the action.

Does anyone know why password and update_password validation is being called in update_attributes? I do not understand why

Comment: No no, :format return the object. When I print: flash[:notice] = "The user #{user.name} is an admin user now" I receive the correct name.

Comment: can post your model file for user where the validations are written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update_attributes` method is calling `save` method with parameter `perform_validations = true` on the object (`user` in your case). So any validations model User has will be performed after calling `update_attributes` method. It's the natural behavior.

For not to perform validations you may want to use `update_attribute` method. It calls `save` method with parameter `perform_validations = false`

**update**

`update_attribute` is deprecated in rails 4 so you may find useable `update_column` instead

Comment: Thank you. I just change "user.update_attributes" to "user.update_columns" and it's working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

`update_attributes` method triggers model validations and callbacks. Try `update_column` method instead of `update_attributes` method.